# SublimeLinter-Csslint not showing error why?

Tags: sublimelinter

I have install sublimelinter and csslint but when i make a error in the css file nothing happens I have install all the neccesary documentation like :

1. Install Node.js (and npm on Linux).

2.Install csslint by typing the following in a terminal:

```
npm install -g csslint
```

what i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sometimes Sublime doesn't pickup the linter after installing it via Package Manager, so you may need to restart your editor.
- Verify that csslint really works by executing it from command line, e.g.:

  `csslint yourfile.css`
- If the above works, enable debug mode for SublimeLinter in the command palette (Shift+Cmd+P -> `Enable Debug Mode`) and then show the console (`View` menu -> `Show Console`). Check if there are any errors.
- Open your CSS file and try to invoke the linter explicitly from the command palette (Shift+Cmd+P -> `SublimeLinter: Lint This View`)

If everything is setup correctly, the linter will show the errors automatically as soon as you open your CSS file.